# The name of the class FormCanDeactivate should end with the suffix Directive

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint

I want to use lint in an excisting Angular Application.
Now i get an lint error for an Guard Class:

The name of the class FormCanDeactivate should end with the suffix Directive (https://angular.io/styleguide#style-02-03) (directive-class-suffix)tslint(1)

Which suffix should i use? Is it right to use "Directive" as the suffix, because i think that Guard are not directives?

```
import { FormGroup, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

import { ComponentCanDeactivate } from '@svn.app/core/guards/ComponentCanDeactivate';
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Directive()
export abstract class FormCanDeactivate extends ComponentCanDeactivate {
    abstract get form(): FormGroup;

    canDeactivate(): boolean {
        if (this.form) {
            return !this.form.dirty;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "*Why should i use Directive as suffix?*" from the link to the angular style guide you posted "*Do append the symbol name with the conventional suffix (such as Component, Directive, Module, Pipe, or Service) for a thing of that type.*" So...what's the question, exactly?

Comment: "*Which suffix should i use?*" again **from the lint message you already have**: "*The name of the class FormCanDeactivate should end with the suffix Directive*"